# Html5 vod straming for Android devices

Tags: html, streaming, protocols, media

What is the best vod straming protocol for html5?
I have been using HLS but it does not work for android devices.

(I am using Helix Media Server)

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of progressive download (a.k.a. pseudo-streaming)? It's supported in HTML5 natively so you won't have troubles playing it in HTML5 mobile browser.